# Identity Server 3 Facebook Partial login using bearer tokens

Tags: facebook, identityserver3

So I was using identity server 3 with facebook as my external provider

I was just wondering if it was possible to do partial external login using bearer tokens

I currently have it working to the point were I can partially login but I would like to redirect back to the app to finish the registration process using a type of partial bearer token or something like that

so the flow I'm after would be

1 from the app click login with facebook
2 redirect to facebook and log in
3 if user is already registered then log in otherwise return to registration page on app
4 register from app login to app

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can return a partial login from the AuthenticateExternal method on your user service. When you create this partial login the ctor can accept any claims you want to pass to your partial login. On the partial login you'd then complete the registration and then return back into IdentityServer by redirecting the user to the "resume URL", which is a claim that can be found in the partial login claims. Sample is here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService -- the `RegisterFirstExternalRegistrationUserService` or the `ExternalRegistrationUserService` are the samples to look at.

Comment: this uses cookies is there a way to get it to return a bearer token which you can pass in the authentication header of your registration call (the outcome being an OAuth registration)

Comment: So the standard way it works is it uses cookies to authenticate the partial login but i would like to replace these cookies with a bearer token so i can make a register call from an external app or website (for example an angular 2 website making oauth calls to the server)

Comment: that's something different -- that's an API, so you'd need to build a different project for that.